# Google Calendar API get events in a specific language

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get the brazilian holidays using Google Calendar through this URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.brazilian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=MyKey&timeMin=2017-01-01T09:11:13.562Z&timeMax=2017-12-31T09:11:13.562Z

This works fine, but I'm getting the holidays in English language, and I need to get it in Portuguese. There is some parameter which I can use to get JSON in another language? Or that is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add `locale` in your [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) request while setting with an allowed value given in [Google Calendar API - Settings](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/settings). Note that `locale` refers to user's locale. So, if you do wish to get list of events in Portuguese, add `locale` with value `pt_BR` or `pt_PT`. If your HTTP request is done successfully, this will return events on the specified calendar.

For the complete list of the supported languages and their corresponding code, see [Language Support](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages) documentation.